# InDesign: Changing language and style of quotation marks doesn't work!

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am currently working on poorly translated documents, proof reading and copywriting. I have quotation marks where the first are at the base line and the closing quotation marks are high up, if that makes sense. I'd like to change to the style where both marks are high up. I found where to do this in the general preferences, under dictionary, where I also set the language to Swedish to be able to perform a language check. However, the change doesn't seem to have any effect, whether I have the whole text marked or not. I still have funny quotation marks and the spelling check shows every single Swedish word as an error.

What is wrong?

Comment: 1. "Language" is a *text* attribute, not a global setting. 2. Once entered, quotation marks do not change.

Comment: I've fixed the grammar and spelling errors for you.  If you think I made any mistakes or altered the meaning too far from your original intention, you can revert the edit or make your own edits.

Answer (score 1):

In order to apply *Typographer's Quotes* to existing text you'll have to do the following:

1. Enter *Edit > Preferences > Dictionary* and select the wanted *Doube Quotes* (and *Single Quotes* if needed) for every language present in your document.

   [image]

   This doesn't change anything in your document. It doesn't apply the wanted quotes. It's simply your *preference* for each language.
2. Make sure that all your text is formatted with the correct language. In your case everything should just be *Swedish*, but you could have multiple languages. This is easily done if you use *Paragraph Styles*.

   [image]
3. Using *Find/Change* you can now perform this simply substitution by pressing *Change All*:

   [image]

   Note that I've simply entered a *straight quotation mark* (the same as an inch symbol: ") in both fields. No need to specify exactly which quotation mark to change to which quotation mark. This way InDesign changes *any* double quotation mark to the appropriate mark according to the language settings.

This method is useful because in some languages you use two different marks for the front and end of a quote, for example in Danish:

[image]

This only works if your text is *well formed*. If you have unwanted spaces in the wrong places InDesign can't place the quotation marks correctly.

If needed you can do this with single quotation marks as well.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the language setting with an open document DOES NOT update the actual text content. So „ will still be „ if you just change the language. The auto spell check (though i admit i never actually use this) may not be able to detect such issues or may have rules built in that may apply differently to what you'd expect.

To turn „ into ” you have to run a replace command on the document.

[image]

Comment: OP still must change the currently applied language to the correct one *before* doing this. InDesign is smart enough (pun!) to change quotes to the ones appropriate for that language.

Comment: Whatever works i guess, i don't trust auto correctors too much and doing a replace like this takes what, 5 seconds?

Comment: Well of course it won't change glyphs already in place. But InDeaign continue to use those cirkus quotation marks even after changing. And my issue is that the language check errs every single Swedish word even after I change dictionary in settings (obviously). Thanks for taking the time, it is appreciated.

Comment: There may be a problem with the way quotation marks are defined in the swedish dictionary in InDesign, in which case...... good luck :)

Comment: No, @Lucian, *both* issues stem from the fact that the wrong language is applied to the text.